# sample data with time dimension for power bi reporting

Tags: powerbi, ssas-tabular

I am trying to implement Relative-Time-Slicer-and-Filter microsoft documentation steps; I couldn't find a sample data that would help me to achieve this.

Could anyone please help me find the a sample data or an existing report with time dimension?

Thank you for giving your valuable time!

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calendarauto-function-dax

Comment: Hello David, I accessed the link you added, but couldn't find any link or source for sample date or pre-built power BI report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find information on this link :https://www.biinsight.com/time-dimension-in-power-bi-and-ssas-tabular-model-supporting-minutes-time-bands/

You will get Dax instructions to build your time dimension in powerBI or in power query.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the info...